# Should questions about error 500 be duplicated to a canonical debugging question?

Tags: discussion, questions, exact-duplicates

In a comment in [How to make localized questions on debugging on-topic?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4648/how-to-make-localized-questions-on-debugging-on-topic/4650?noredirect=1#comment6963_4650), I'm suggested that the standard process to debug is to:

> disable all the plugins, switch to the default theme, then enable them 1 by 1 until the problem comes back, use WP_DEBUG, check PHP error logs

Would there be a canonical question about debugging generic errors, and duplicate future questions to it?

Comment: We might already have a doc for that, or it might be on .org, tbh that was just what I could think of off the top of my head. I hadn't considered asking a wide ranging "How to debug" Q to mark others as duplicates, though it would need a well defined scope else it'd be massively broad. How to setup basic XDebug/PHPStorm for example wouldn't fit on this stack, or how to configure PHP error logs in Nginx, it'd have to be WP specific